# Sessions aren't be saved to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-state

**I have a file sess_function.php**

This file lists the various (6) functions used to control sessions..

```
function _open()
{
    try{
        // Open the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    } //try
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error CONNECTING.";
        file_put_contents('PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    } //catch
}   

## Kill Connection to Mysql (Using PDO) 
function _close(){
$dbh = null;
}

## Read a current session 
function _read($id){
    try{
        // Open the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        // Begin Query
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = '$id'");
        $sth->execute();

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error. READING";
        file_put_contents('PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    } //catch

    ## return '';
}

## Write to current session 
function _write($id, $data){
    // WRITE Vars
    try{
        // Open the database
##      require_once('dbi.php');
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        // Begin Query
        $access = time();
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $access = mysql_real_escape_string($access);
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES ('$id', '$access', '$data')");
        $sth->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error. REPLACING SESSION VAL";
        file_put_contents('PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    } //catch

}

## Destroy current session
function _destroy($id){   
    try{
        // Open the database
##      require_once('dbi.php');
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        // Begin Query
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = '$id'");
        $sth->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error.";
        file_put_contents('PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    } //catch  
}

## Clean old session data out 
function _clean($max){
    try{
        // Open the database
##      require_once('dbi.php');
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        // Begin Query
        $old = time() - $max;
        $old = mysql_real_escape_string($old);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE  access < '$old'");
        $sth->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Oops, We're experiencing an error. DEL FROM SESSION";
        file_put_contents('PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    } //catch

}
```

and **index.php**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
###### Require Database ######                              ////////////////////////
####### DB Config Setting #######
$host ='localhost'; //////////////
$dbname ='mydb';//////////
$user ='root';     //////////////
$pass ='';         //////////////
/////////////////////////////////


                        ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
###### Start session                                        ////////////////////////
session_start();                                            ////////////////////////
###### Call Session Functions Include ######                ////////////////////////            
require_once('src/cfg/sess_function.php');                  ////////////////////////
###### Call function as contained in sess_function() ######                       //
session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');  //                            
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The table looks like:
[image: img1]

The problem is: it gives me no problem, but nothing is stored in the `sessions` table...

if I UNCOMMENT `session_start();` it throws these warnings:

```
Oops, We're experiencing an error. READING
Warning: session_start() Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by sess_function.php:33)index.php on line 12

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started sess_function.php:33) in index.php on line 12
```

Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message is what you should be looking at. PHP needs to send HTTP header data (a cookie), but there's already been some output in sess_function.php. Header data cannot be sent after regular output (say, `echo`). You print "Oops, We're experiencing an error. READING", which is the output PHP complains about. Removing all echo statements will resolve the session problem.

Then: the `$dbname`, `$user`, `$pass` and `$host` variables weren't set. `global $dbname, $host, $user, $pass;` declarations fixed that.

Finally: session_set_save_handler must be called before session_start, because otherwise PHP won't call the custom functions. The output already sent errors happened because the MySQL errors were triggered before session_start finished running (the MySQL errors occured *during* session_start)

Comment: So, just remove all the `echo`s in the `catch{}` block?

Comment: Yes. You can still log to a file / db / log server / whatever if you want.

Comment: On second thought: moving session_start before the echo statements will also work, of course.

Comment: I tried commenting out all the `echo` statements in the catch blocks and it doesnt give me an error... but also doesnt insert into the `sessions` table either..

Comment: `session_start()` is before everything exept the function `session_set_save_handler`

Comment: What does the log file contain?

Comment: Please see the updated index.php. `The log file contains:SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selectedSQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selectedSQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selectedSQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selectedSQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selectedSQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected`

Comment: It's what the error says; no database is selected. In the provided code $dbname is not set; if it's set outside the functions, you'll have to declare them global in the functions using it (and $host as well).

Comment: Please see updated index.php . I harded the db values into the script, its not writing an error anymore... but it also still isnt sending to the database

Comment: The values of the session that is into `sessions`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8970/discussion-between-abesto-and-user975947)

Answer (score 0):

Why is your session_start() commented? Try turning it on

Are you on auto session start?

Comment: Please see the above added errors if I uncomment session_start();